# Matplotlib: force normalized scientific notation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot with y-values in the range [-8.7 x 10<sup>-3</sup>, 8.7 x 10<sup>-3</sup>]. I've forced scientific notation for all numbers using the following:

```
ax.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='both', scilimits=(0,0), useOffset=False)
```

However, the y-axis shows 10<sup>-2</sup> as exponent and ticks {-0.5, 0.0, 0.5}. How can I force matplotlib to use [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#Normalized_notation) scientific notation, such that I'd have 10<sup>-3</sup> of exponent and ticks {-5, 0, 5}? I have looked in the documentation, but I can't find relevant information.

*Edited for clarity.*

Comment: It seems that matplotlib default ticks for this data is [-0.01, -0.005, 0., 0.005, 0.01]. Given the first and last ticks, it makes sense to use 10<sup>-2</sup> as exponent. However, these ticks never appear, as the view_lims are [-0.0087, 0.0087]. This creates the ambiguity that prompted me to ask this question.

The temporary fix is to remove the first and last ticks. I'm not sure if this behavior is intended or if this could be considered a bug.